# PHP Regex for Latin + Special Chars but not <>%=

Tags: regex

I am trying to match latin characters plus things like @ € ; - but not <>%=

I got this pattern working:

```
^[\p{Latin}€@,.!?\s\/\d\-\+,.:()?!"„‟'§_]*$
```

But I would like to change it to something like this, to avoid adding all the allowed special chars one by one.

```
^[\p{Latin}]+?[^#%<>]+$
```

This pattern actually seems th work for strings like

```
Abc < Cbd (No match)
This is @ works (match)
```

but as soon as the string starts with a special Char it fails to match

```
@ work (no match)
```

It seems to me that the second part of the pattern is allowing anyting but <>%= when the sentence was started with a latin char. I even can write:

```
a ㄓㄨㄥ ㄨㄣˊ ㄗ dkjfalkfj
```

and get a match.

It somehow seems logical to me but can't get it and don't know how to get a better way to achive a working pattern.

Comment: The "best" way depends on what the regex flavor is, but you may try `^(?:(?![<>%=])[\p{Latin}\s\d\p{P}\p{S}])*$`

Comment: Your expression is expecting there to be at least one latin character at the start of the string (this does not include @) because of the quantifier. `+` expects to match between one and unlimited times. Try using `*` instead as it matches between 0 and unlimited.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works fine! I already tryed adding the '*'  this fixes the @ at the beginning but still allows Chinese Chars in the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:(?![<>%=])[\p{Latin}\s\d\p{P}\p{S}])*$
```

It matches:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:(?![<>%=])[\p{Latin}\s\d\p{P}\p{S}])*` - zero or more occurrences of any char matched with `[\p{Latin}\s\d\p{P}\p{S}]` character class (Latin letters `\p{Latin}`, whitespaces `\s`, digits `\d`, punctuation proper (`\p{P}`) and symbols (`\p{S}`)) that is not `<`, `>`, `%` and `=`
- `$` - end of a string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yu5Qgc/2).